# react style background css property

Tags: css, reactjs

How do I apply the css property `background` inline in react?

I tried passing the following object, which didn't work:

```
let style = {
    background:
        `linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
          ), url("${ place.imgUri }") no-repeat center center cover`
};
```

Note: it does work when only adding the url property.

The reason why I want this is because I need to add a linear-gradient as well, aside from a dynamic background-url.
If I define it via a css class rule, it is being overwritten by the inline-style.

Edit: I really don't understand why to close this question because off topic. If a css label is needed, just say so in the comments (?).

Comment: `noRepeat`  should be `no-repeat`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli It didn't change unfortunately, the inline-style isn't applieid. I thought all css properties added in react should be camel-case.

Comment: indeed that is not the problem. But the camel-case refers to the css property not its value. The real problem is that `linear-gradient` creates an *image* so it actually refers to the `background-image` property. To have two backgrounds you need to use a `,` (*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Adding the `,` and using `no-repeat` also didn't fix it yet. (Edited in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `,` in the `background` shorthand rule separates 2 `background`s, not just 2 `background-image`s.

So if you need 1 shorthand rule that overrides all of the properties:

```
background:
  `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)) no-repeat center center / cover,
   url("${ place.imgUri }") no-repeat center center / cover`
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Gabriele Petrioli, it worked.
I just added:

```
let style = {
    backgroundImage:
        `linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
          ), url("${ place.imgUri }")`
};
```

Then just added css class properties additionally:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

The are a couple of issues with the original code.

First, because `linear-gradient` refers to the `background-image` property so you actually need two backgrounds, you need to use `,` to separate them.

Secondly, the syntax for `background-size` in the shorthand version is after `/`.

So it should be

```
let style = {
    background:
        `linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
          ), url("${ place.imgUri }") no-repeat center center / cover`
};
```

Comment: `no-repeat center center / cover` are applied only to the 2nd background, not to `linear-gradient` (FYI I didn't downvote, the comments under question were very helpful)

Comment: @Aprillion no worries. thanks for spotting the misplaced `,` as well :)

Comment: @Aprillion also linear gradient does not need these props as it will by definition fill its container without repeating.

Comment: does it overwrite properties that were explicitly set by lower priority rules, e.g. in `background-size: x; background: linear-gradient(y)`? even if it does, I would prefer to explicitly set the rules to communicate the intention that I wanted to overwrite those properties (for easier refactoring in the future) - assuming there are actual lower priority rules that contradict what I want to achieve